# Truncate table privilege without stored procedures

Tags: oracle

SYSTEM creates several tables, and would like to grant userA the ability to truncate tables. On oracle's docs, the minimum privilege is :

```
GRANT DROP ANY TABLE TO userA
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707

DROP ANY TABLE as stated is too powerful of a privilege to be granted to a user, and from looking around there is no way to limit the tables the user can truncate with it.

The proper way as previous topics has touched on is to use stored procedures:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure truncateTables
AS
BEGIN
execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE table1';
end;
/

GRANT EXECUTE on system.truncateTables TO userA;
```

However, if I want to avoid using any stored procedures at all, is there an alternative way to allow a user that is not the table owner to truncate tables, but not with a privilege that is potentially destructive like "DROP ANY TABLE" ?

Comment: Nope, those are the two options.  Why do you want users to be truncating tables in the first place?  That's generally only something that you'd want to do as part of a batch load in which case calling a stored proc seems like a pretty reasonable approach.

Comment: The user could be just a database manager with minimum privileges and would run batch jobs to truncate a large log database daily, that was the goal at least. Thanks for the clarification, it would seem that stored procs are the only option.

Comment: @user10518 Would a proxy connection help?  It would allow you to logon as the owner of the tables, which would let you truncate the table without giving away the system account's password.

Comment: @JonHeller Hiding the password is not really the issue here. I just thought that there might be a not-so "all or nothing" way to truncate tables without stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do it without procedure.

**you can do it dynamically like this:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure pr_truncate_table(p_table_name varchar2) is
begin

     execute immediate 'truncate table ' || p_table_name || '';


 end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

A work-around that I have used is to grant delete to the other user, then use a delete instead of truncate to remove the rows. This is NOT a proper truncate as it does not clear the used storage, but it allows the same tasks to be achieved.

With the table owner account

```
GRANT delete on Table_Name to "User_Account";
```

With the other account

```
Delete from Table_Name where 1=1;
```